# set jinja2 variable default value as list

Tags: jinja2

How to use the jinja2 default filter to set the variable as list type?

I was trying to set a jinja2 variable's default value as a list type. Then perform the for loop from it.

```
{% for row_af in {{ af_name | default(['ipv4', 'ipv6']) }} %}
Address-family:     {{ row_af }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I got the following error from it.

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: {% endfor %}
fatal: [pl1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: \n{% for row_af in {{ af_name | default(['ipv4', 'ipv6']) }} %}\nAddress-family:     {{ row_af }}\n{% endfor %}\n\n"}
```

The default filter works well if I just set a "string" type value to it. Wondering how can I set it to "list" or "dictionary".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never nest Jinja template markers. If you're already inside a Jinja template expression (`{{...}}` or `{%...%}`), you can simply refer to variables by name (`myvar`); you don't need `{{ myvar }}`.

Your template expression should look something like:

```
{% for row_af in af_name | default(['ipv4', 'ipv6']) %}
Address-family:     {{ row_af }}
{% endfor %}
```

Assuming that `af_name` is undefined, the above will produce:

```
Address-family:     ipv4
Address-family:     ipv6
```